Looking for a software/app for collecting RR-Interval data and time stamps from Polar H10 recordings
I am currently planning an experiment where I will collect heart rate variability data among other measures. I am using the Polar H10 chest strap, but have not figured out what app or software is best to collect RR-interval data.
As I collect HRV data over a longer period of time and want to compare some specific time intervals from the recording period, I need time stamps. However, the elite HRV app, for example, does not provide time stamps. In the Polar Flow app, I couldn't find any RR-interval data at all.
Does anyone have recommendations for apps or software that provide RR-data and time stamps?
I appreciate any input!
